# Redirecting View by Id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, actionlink

I have 2 tables **tbl_client** and **tbl_branch** linked with the **client_id**. I have created a **ClientController** and a **BranchController**.

Now I need to control the branch under client view. I have and ActionLink

```
@Html.ActionLink("Branch Management", "Index", "Branch", new {id = item.client_id},null)
```

This will redirect to Index view in branch controller, where the list of branches according to client id is filtered and return the view.

Now I have a create link in this view and I need to redirect it to the Create Page which will Create the Branch Under the Client currently active.

Comment: Please Mention the problem you are getting in this with some more information.

Comment: I think you want to pass Client_id in Branch created page with actionlink..?

Comment: Yes.. I need to pass Client_id in Branch Create Page so that I can create the Branches under the Client

Answer (score 0):

just put the client_id in a viewbag from your Branch-> Index actionresult.

```
Public ActionResult Index(string id){
  ViewBag.ClientId=id;
}
```

now goto its view; Index.cshtml and say,

```
@Html.ActionLink("New Client", "Create", "Client", new {id = ViewBag.ClientId});
```

Comment: I have used ViewBag as you suggested but I cannot redirect back to the same page after I go to Create Page .The ViewBag gets null value when I go back to the listing page

Answer (score 0):

Just Make a Link into View as:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Branch Create", "Create", "Branch", new {id = item.client_id})
```

and on Server side (i.e. In Controller) use action as:

```
    //GET 
    public ActionResult Create(long Client_ID)
    {
        var NewBranch=new BranchViewModel{Client_ID=Client_ID};
        return View(NewBranch);
    }

    //POST
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(BranchViewModel Branch)
    {
        //Code to Create New Entry
    }
```

Maybe this can help you.

Comment: It doesnot take id = item.client_id  in the ActionLink .. I have managed to use Model instead of client .. I have tried ViewBag too but no good